# What does line impedance stabilization mean?

Tags: impedance, impedance-matching, characteristic-impedance

What exactly does line impedance stabilization mean?

What parameters of line impedance are stabilized and how?

How does line impedance / source impedance vary with frequency?

Comment: it varies because its related to capacitance and inductance of the line. and you know calculating reactance is depending on the capacitor/inductor value + the frequency.

Answer (score 2):

It is all in the name. A Line Impedance Stabilization Network does just that. The impedance of AC lines can vary wildly depending on where you are, how your house/outlet is wired, nearby radio stations, etc.

The LISN is basically a large low-pass filter that gives you a "quiet" AC signal to, as Jasen said, measure conducted emissions from a unit. Different standards require different LISNs. For example, the LISN used in CISPR22 is diferent than MIL-STD-461. The end goal is the same though. The LISN ensures that you will read similar conducted emissions levels at different test locations.

When performing a conducted scan you connect your spectrum analyzer to a 50ohm impedance within the LISN. I am attaching an image I did for work not too long ago that shows the gain and phase across frequency. This shows the LISN used for CISPR11/22. R3 is the impedance you would measure across, R1 is where you would attach the unfiltered AC. You can see I'm doing the sweep from the "output" which connects to the unit.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An LISN is used to provide a way to measure power-line borne noise originating from an appliance.

Typical wiring at an installation is nothing like a transmission line, the impedance is all over the places and there are many branches and stubs

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_Impedance_Stabilization_Network

inside the box is a large resonant filter built with wide-band air core inductors.